# What is the difference between `{ }` and `[ ]`?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, what is the difference between

```
 var stack = {};
```

and

```
var stack = [];
```

Comment: The first is an object. The second is an array.

Comment: JS basics are covered in tutorials: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is an empty object and the second is an empty array.

Comment: @Neal - My hands shake so they usually fly over the keyboard pretty fast. Usually I end up with loads of typos but this time I got lucky ;)